# keyword "this" in a normal javascript function

Tags: javascript, this

console.log(this) in global context and inside a normal function should result in a "Window" object in the console, according to the resource that I was going through.

I get "Window" object in console when I do console.log(this), outside a function, but when I do,

```
function value() {
console.log(this);
}
```

value();

I get undefined printed in the console.
Can someone explain, why is that?

Comment: Your `value` must be running in strict mode

Comment: You are running this in strict mode.